# How to install Python 2.7, on Windows 10, to be used for SleepPY

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, sleeppy

I need to install Python 2.7 onto my Windows 10 OS so that I can run the Python library SleepPY which requires Python 2.7.

But when I installed Python 2.7 MSI 64bit for Windows 10, it doesn't run.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed python-2.7.18.amd64.msi from python.org
(which also installed pip 10.2.3)

Added to Windows 10 ENV VAR SYS PATH:

```
c:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts         
C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts
```

Then at CMD prompt:
pip install sleeppy

..and sleeppy fully installed.